# WebGL disabled when embedding Plotly in PyQt

Tags: pyqt5, webgl, plotly-python

I am trying to embed a plotly code in a PyQt GUI. My plotly code needs to receive a huge amount of data, which was not a problem at all when it was running alone. But when I am trying to put it in a PyQt code, the performance is not good and I receive a warning about WebGL. Apparently WebGL is not activated. I tried to correct it by adding this line :

```
self.browser.page().settings().setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.WebGLEnabled, True)
```

but it didn't change anything.

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

import numpy          as np
import pandas         as pd
import plotly.express as px

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, df, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)
        
        # WebGL enabled: this line appears to be useless
        self.browser.page().settings().setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.WebGLEnabled, True)
        
        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.browser)

        fig = px.scatter(df, x='x', y='y', color='lambda', log_x=True, log_y=True, opacity=0.10)
        self.browser.setHtml(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
        
        self.resize(1000,800)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    N = 20000
    
    col0 = 400 + 400 * np.random.random(N)
    col1 = np.linspace(1,N,N) * np.random.normal(1,0.5,N)
    col2 = np.linspace(1,N,N) * np.random.normal(1,5,N)
    result = np.array([col0, col1, col2]).T
    df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['lambda', 'x', 'y'])
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget = Widget(df)
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

Here is what I am obtaining if I am putting a value too big for N:

```
[1784:7704:1202/161033.541:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(10941)] [.WebGL-000001AB7779E4D0]PERFORMANCE WARNING: Attribute 0 is disabled. This has significant performance penalty
js: [.WebGL-000001AB7779E4D0]PERFORMANCE WARNING: Attribute 0 is disabled. This has significant performance penalty
```

I have to say that even if I have this warning, the code is not crashing... but is taking seriously too long when N is huge.